# Wrap two promise in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-http

I have some issue with the return of promise. Before, during an http call, I used a function like this returning one promise:

```
get_data: function (url)
{
     let timestamp = new Date();
     return $http({
         method: "GET",
         url: url
         headers: {
              'timestamp': timestamp,
         }
     }).then(
            function successCallback(response)
            {

                console.dir("Response:");
                console.dir(response["data"]);

                return (response["data"])
            },
            function errorCallback(response)
            {
                console.dir(response);
                return response;
            });
    },
```

It was quite straight forward and I could use it like this:

```
get_data('my_awesome_url').then(function(response){
    let my_awesome_data = response
})
```

The culprit is the timestamp thingy. I use it for some authentification, the why is not important, but by getting it from the client side I was quite often victim of bad horloge or system local set in another langage.

My solution was to create a function that request a server timestamp . But by doing this I must first wait for the timestamp request to hand, then launch another request and... wait for it to end.
This is where I don't really know what to do. My code look like this:

```
get_data: function (url)
{
     let timestamp = new Date();
     get_timestamp().then(function(){
         return $http({
             method: "GET",
             url: url
             headers: {
                  'timestamp': timestamp,
             }
         }).then(
                function successCallback(response)
                {

                    console.dir("Response:");
                    console.dir(response["data"]);

                    return (response["data"])
                },
                function errorCallback(response)
                {
                    console.dir(response);
                    return response;
                });
        });
    },
```

But I'm not sure what I should return. Should I return the get_timestamp promise and in the "then" wait for the other request to end? Should I make the get_timestamp a synchronous call because after all it's just a little date string?
I used the old function all the way accross my code so a way to just keep the old use (with only one then) would be awesome.

As always thanks all.

Comment: `return get_timestamp().then(function(){...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write it that way:

```
get_data: function(url) {
  return get_timestamp() // request the timestamp this returns a promise
    .then(function(timestamp) {   // on which then is called wich itself returns a promise.
                         // the callback of this then is called as soon 
                         // as the promise returned by timestamp
                         // is resolved
      return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: url
        headers: {
          'timestamp': timestamp,
        }
      }) // here you return the Promise that is created by the $http
    })
    .then(function(response) { // the callback of this then is called as soon
                               // as the previous promise was resolved

      console.dir("Response:");
      console.dir(response["data"]);

      return (response["data"])
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      console.dir(response);
      return response;
    });
},
```

First of all I would use:

```
.then(function(response) {
  console.dir("Response:");
  console.dir(response["data"]);

  return (response["data"])
})
.catch(function(response) {
  console.dir(response);
  return response;
});
```

Instead of

```
.then(
  function successCallback(response) {

    console.dir("Response:");
    console.dir(response["data"]);

    return (response["data"])
  },
  function errorCallback(response) {
    console.dir(response);
    return response;
  });
})
```

Because it is easier to read later if you have longer chains.

The `return` returns the last Promise that was created through the chain, the one that was returned by the call `.catch(function(response) {...}`

Comment: @t-niese Named functions are a good thing for everybody and make it easier to understand the call stack if errors are thrown. If OP is ok with slightly more verbose code, you should not discourage it.

Comment: @skylize it was less about the named function then about the `.then(success, error)` vs `.then(callback).catch(callback)`. Using `.catch` makes it easier to find those `.catch` statements later. With a `.then(success, error)` those error callbacks are not that easy to see/find. The OP catches the error so this won't appear in any error stack, so in this particular case the named function is less likely to have a benefit.

Comment: Just to make sure, except obviously the syntax, the .catch and the .then(success, error) work the same way ?

Comment: @t-niese Ah, ok. Personally I feel that using `.then(success, error)` in many situations can be helpful to visually clarify which promises have potential to throw. Where I would use `.catch(error) as more of a fallback. But that seems mostly stylistic, and not really going to affect the final result.

Comment: @skylize @RaphaelTodo oh in this particular case my soultion is wrong I'll update my answer accoringly. I forgot that angular does not pass an error to the reject. In this case the `then` is a better solution over the catch and has to be placed directly with the `$http` in the callback.

Comment: @RaphaelTodo They are interchangeable in many cases, but they have a subtle difference that can matter a lot. `.then(success, error)` will either go to `success` or `error`, catching errors before this point in the code, but not errors in the `success` function. `.then(success).catch(error)` will catch errors from before this point plus any errors thrown by `success`.

Answer (score 1):

You should chain the Promises and return the result of the chain:

```
function get_data(url) {
  return get_timestamp()
    .then((timestamp) => {
      return $http({
         method: "GET",
         url: url,
         headers: {
           timestamp: timestamp
         }
      });
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.dir("Response:");
      console.dir(response["data"]);

      return response["data"];
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      console.dir(response);
      return response;
    });
}
```

Note that we only need one `.catch` at the end of the chain to catch all exceptions.